# java parameterized test with 2 methods

Tags: java, parameterized

Hi Im am trying to use a parameterized  test for my java code. I have 2 methods that i wanted to test. One that coverts miles to kilometer and another that converts kilometer to miles. is there a way to test both methods for a parameterized  test or do i have to create another parameterized test for each method?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class testLengthConverter {

private double lengths; 
private double expected; 


public testLengthConverter(double expected , double length){
  this.expected = expected; 
    this.lengths = length; 

}


 @Parameters
 public static  Collection<Object[]> lengthKm(){
return Arrays.asList( new Object[][]
        { {8.04672000307346, 5} , 
        {0.8046720003073461, .5},
        {3.10685596,5}, 
        {0.310685596, .5}});
}

 @Parameters
 public static  Collection<Object[]> lengthMile(){
return Arrays.asList( new Object[][]

        {});
 }

 @Test
 public void calcMile () 
 {
LengthConverter lengthMile= new LengthConverter();
assertEquals(expected,lengthMile.kmToMile(lengths),.0001);
 }

 @Test
 public void calcKm () 
 {
LengthConverter lengthKm= new LengthConverter();
assertEquals(expected,lengthKm.mileToKm(lengths), .0001);
        }

 }
```

Comment: Different test method is better, it will narrowed resukt in case if failure

Comment: I second @JigarJoshi. Remember, you create tests so your software can fail when something goes wrong and enable you to find the error quick and certainly; if not like that, it'll miss the whole point - your tests will "rot" and ultimately lose value in the long run.

Comment: I know that this isnt the best way to test a program, but this is for a homework assignment. I was just trying to figure out if it was possible to test 2 methods separably for a parameterized test. Thanks for the input btw